# I need a regex pattern for html <a> tag

Tags: c#, html, regex

I need a regex to find this pattern in HTML page for tag `<a>`. 
Each `<a>` has this structure :

```
   <a rel="EUR,USD,1,2" href="/currencycharts/?from=USD&amp;to=EUR">0.90043</a>
```

what is problem : my pattern for regex is  this :

```
  @"<a\s.*?rel=.*?href=""/currencycharts/?from=.*?;to=.*>\d.\d\d\d\d ?</a>
```

but I can not find the `<a>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Parsing HTML with regex is like using a hammer when you need a screwdriver. It's the wrong tool for the job: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/945456

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing your other examples, I would start with this.

`<a\s.*?rel=.*?href="/currencycharts/\?from=.*;to=.*>\d\.\d+ ?</a>`

`?from` needs to be `\?from`

`\d.\d\d\d\d` has 4 numbers after the decimal, but in your example, you have 5.  I would suggest `\d\.\d+` or `\d\.\d*` *Also note the `\.` instead of `.`.  This will match the period character exclusively instead of 'any' character.

Also, as a note, there are online regex testers that help to quickly diagnose issues with regex patterns.  Here is one for C#: http://regexstorm.net/tester

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
<a\s.*?rel=.*?href=""/currencycharts/\?from=.*?;to=.*?>\d\.\d\d\d\d\d?</a>
                                     ↑               ↑   ↑          ↑
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aD2rI1/11)